# Azure B2C - Custom policy not working when user change password

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using b2c custom policy, when user logged in -> reset password-> enter signin name and email address -> receives verification code -> validate code -> click on continue it throws my custom error which I setup under "UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationStringsAreNotEqual" key.

I have verified email address its correct for user in b2c. I am using signin thorugh username not email address.

I am not sure what other reason its failing for? Also, I wanted to know if there is any way to avoid email address verification part (we have some users without email address)?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to share the technical profile and associated claims transform for anyone to help.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923615/azure-ad-b2c-password-reset-policy-without-email-verification-step?rq=1) link

Comment: Do you mind posting an answer so that this issue can be treated as archived?

Comment: Following link helped me to fix the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923615/azure-ad-b2c-password-reset-policy-without-email-verification-step?rq=1